# Is it true that NUnit requires "magic strings" while MSTest does not?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unit-testing, nunit, mstest

I'm trying to decide on a unit testing framework. I was just reading [this comparison between NUnit and MSTest](http://www.barebonescoder.com/2010/06/mstest-vs-nunit-with-visual-studio-2010-tdd/), and in the example under "Our Third Test – NUnit", magic strings are used to refer to a property name, while the MSTest version does not.

Here is the MSTest version:

```
Assert.IsNotNull(b.Players.Where(x => x.Name.Equals("Cross")));
Assert.IsNotNull(b.Players.Where(x => x.Name.Equals("Nought")));
```

Here is the NUnit version:

```
Assert.That(b.Players, Has.Some.With.Property("Name").EqualTo("Nought"));
Assert.That(b.Players, Has.Some.With.Property("Name").EqualTo("Cross"));
```

The author (bearbonescoder) claims that the NUnit version is better because its fluent style is more readable, while several commenters disagreed because NUnit requires "magic strings" for property names. The author did not appear to address this criticism, but to me, this seems like a rather serious disadvantage for NUnit when it comes to refactoring.

(As an aside, I love LINQ, so I don't find MSTest statements even remotely difficult to grok. And as an aside of an aside, I believe the LINQ queries the author used in his example are incorrect--a `Where` expression that results in no records would return an empty `IEnumerable<T>` not `null`.)

Anyway, my questions:

1. Is it true that NUnit requires "magic strings" as in the above example, or is there a different and reasonably efficient way to write the same assertions without magic strings? (Note: I'm referring only to "Name", not to "Naught" and "Cross".)
2. Should I care?

Comment: The MSTest version doesn't make sense to me -- `b.Players.Where` will never return `null`, and furthermore the syntax you show is perfectly legal in NUnit as well.

Comment: @Kirk, yes, I mentioned that (the part about the example being incorrect).

Comment: ah yes, sorry I missed that.  But the example is still completely invalid, IMO -- apples and oranges.   The syntax you show in the MSTest version also works in the NUnit version.  The NUnit version *also* supports the `Assert.That` syntax, in addition to the `Assert.IsNotNull` syntax MSTest is using.  So if your reason for using MSTest is that it supports a syntax that NUnit also supports, I'm not sure I follow.

Comment: @Kirk, gotcha, you should put that in an answer so I can upvote you and such :)

Comment: Don't forget that NUnit Assert methods aren't magic. They just throw exceptions when things don't match. So you can write whatever kind of assertion methods you want as long as they throw exceptions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The only thing that should matter in the end if the assertion you make is valid or not. There are several ways to check for things, both in NUnit and MSTest. You don't have to use the fluent syntax, you could write the same assertion like this, for example:

```
Assert.True(b.Players.Any(p => p.Name == "Cross");
```

Personally, I prefer the fluent syntax for simple(r) checks, such as

```
Assert.That(b.Name, Is.EqualTo("Stan"));
```

or

```
Assert.That(b.Players, Is.Not.Null);
```

In the end you should use whatever you find more readable, and not bother yourself with the implementation details of a particular testing framework. I know this really doesn't answer your question, but I believe it shouldn't be an issue due to the fact that it's possible to do things in more than one way.

(As a side note, I prefer NUnit because of the fluent syntax, but also things like `Assert.Throws` and its opposite `Assert.DoesNotThrow`, as well as convenient assertion classes such as `CollectionAssert` and `StringAssert`, none of which are present in MSTest.

Comment: From what I can tell he's worried less about the actual syntax and more about how NUnit requires your property to be a string, instead of using the actual strongly typed object. I'm curious on this as well, can NUnit make use of strongly typed objects?

Comment: Actually, it totally does answer my question. Thanks you and +1.

Comment: @Mike M. NUnit does not require you to use strings for property names. It can make use of strongly typed objects. It always has. The `Has.Some.With.Property` syntax is a special case. There are dozens if of ways to assert things in NUnit and almost none of them use strings for property names.

Comment: @Mike, I think what hmemcpy is saying is that NUnit does *not* require your property to be a string. The author of the blog post I was referring to just happened to structure his assert statement that way, but there's no reason that particular syntax is required.

Comment: Exactly. In fact, I raised an eyebrow reading and trying to figure out what `Has.Some.With.Property` means, since I have't really seen it used before. There are simpler ways :)

Comment: One advantage with fluent syntax over LINQ is that NUnit will automatically produce a handy error message that details what condition was not met. This way you can just read the test logs to find out what's wrong without having to write your own error custom error message.